# AS3: How do I get dynamic loader URL from LoaderInfo in Event Listener Function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, loader, loaderinfo

I'm loading many pictures, and am using an array to do so.

```
loader[i].load(new URLRequest(picture[i]));
```

My Event Listener function is enabled like this:

```
loader[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
```

My onComplete event handler shows this:

```
trace(e.target); //OUTPUT: [object LoaderInfo]
```

I've looked for properties in LoaderInfo that might identify which loader initiated the listener (the value of "i") so that I can putz around with each one specifically, like this:

```
bitmapDataArr[i] = e.target.content.bitmapData;
bmVisArr[i] = new Bitmap(bitmapDataArr[i]);
```

But cannot determine which "i" initiated the specific instance of the listener.

Any ideas? I tried giving a name to LoaderInfo to no avail. I still can't extract the pesky little identifying number.

**EDIT** showing loop for loaders and onComplete function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    loader[i] = new Loader();
    loader[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);           
    loader[i].load(new URLRequest(letter[i]));
}

private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("e.target",e.target); //OUTPUT: e.target    [object LoaderInfo]
    var LI:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
    var eNum:int = (????);
    bitmapDataArr[eNum] = e.target.content.bitmapData;
    bmVisArr[eNum] = new Bitmap(bitmapDataArr[eNum]);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered creating custom class based on `URLLoader` and store the information there?

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Never made a custom class, wouldn't know where to even start on that... Are you saying that I *can't* get the "i" number from loaderInfo?

Comment: The source of your problem is distributing connected objects across several arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll somehow need to bring `i` value to `onComplete` function. For example, in the `this` context or thru an argument.

P.S.: It's easier to use weak ref. Dictionaries instead of deleting properties, though I don't know much about AS3.

Here's an example that also shows how to remove the event listeners (including their callback functions):

```as3
/* An object containing callback
 * functions used along with event listeners.
 */
const callbacks: Object = {};


/* This function will re-declare and hoist i
 * in itself. */
private function loop(i: uint): void {
    loader[i] = new Loader;

    const wrapped =
    callbacks[i] = function wrapper(...args) {
        // Pass all arguments (respectively event and i)
        onComplete.apply(null, args);

        // Function#apply(thisContext, arguments)
        // Rest exp. isn't implemented yet, else we could just do:
        // onComplete(...args);
    };

    loader[i].contentLoaderInfo
        .addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, wrapped, false,
            0, true);

    loader[i].load(new URLRequest(letter[i]));
};

for (var i: uint = 0; i < 10; ++i) loop(i);

private function onComplete(e: Event, i: uint): void {
    const loaderInfo: LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;

    bitmapDataArr[i] = e.target
        .content.bitmapData;

    bmVisArr[i] = new Bitmap(bitmapDataArr[i]);

    loader[i].contentLoaderInfo
        .removeEventListener(
            Event.COMPLETE, callbacks[i]
        );

    // Deletes the property that stores
    // the function inside callbacks
    delete callbacks[i];
}
```

Comment: I heard inline functions as listeners are not a good idea. How can you remove that listener again? How will the Loader object be garbage collected if you can't?

Comment: @null The simply way to remove the listener is to declare the function inside the wrapped function at the loop, then pass it as a reference in `onComplete` arguments. I think it'd be better to have a object with these wrapped functions, so, when we're gonna remove each listener, we can remove wrapped functions together by using `delete` operator

Comment: @null About the last question, it depends if the op is using the loader object. He/she didn't show his/her code at all

Comment: @null I also agree and see why inline functions as listeners aren't a good idea, that is like free it in the air, and in this way we can't handle changes with it

Comment: Great explanation and edit, thanks, +1. I think it's important to address such issues when it comes to possibly large objects like loaded image files.

Answer (score 3):

Since posting this question, I've been utilizing the following class. It takes in  an integer (number pictures to load) and gives public access to an array of Sprites in the Array "ShapeArr."

Each sprite's name property is derived from its URL name. (name:"pic1" from loaded url "assets/pic1.png")

I was having trouble with the whole concept/implementation of inline functions, and have been using this approach instead.

```
package {
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MultipleImageLoader extends Sprite {
    {private var pic:Array = [
        "assets/pic1.png",  "assets/pic2.png",  "assets/pic3.png",  "assets/pic4.png",
    ]}

    private var loader:Array = [];

    public var ShapeArr:Array = [];
    public var bitmapDataArr:Array = [];
    public var bmVisArr:Array = [];     
    private var shapeText:Array = [];       
    private var picArray:Array = [];

    private var count:int = 0;
    private var loaderCounter:int = 0;
    private var numPicsToLoad:int;
    private var a:String;
    public var loaded:Boolean = false;

    public function MultipleImageLoader(numPics:int):void {
        numPicsToLoad = numPics;
        loaded = false;

        init();
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        if (hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE)) {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }
        picArray = new Array;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numPicsToLoad; i++) {
            picArray.push(i);
        }
        initiateLoaders();
    }

    private function initiateLoaders():void{
        loader[loaderCounter] = new Loader;
        loader[loaderCounter].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);

        a = pic[picArray[loaderCounter]];
        //trace("shapecolor load:", a);
        shapeText[loaderCounter] = (a.substr(16, a.length - 20));
        loader[loaderCounter].load(new URLRequest(a ) );
    }

    private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
        //trace("sssssssssssssssssssssssssshapecolor");
        bitmapDataArr[loaderCounter] = e.target.content.bitmapData;
        bmVisArr[loaderCounter] = new Bitmap(bitmapDataArr[loaderCounter]);
        bmVisArr[loaderCounter].scaleX = .1;
        bmVisArr[loaderCounter].scaleY = .1;
        bmVisArr[loaderCounter].x =-bmVisArr[loaderCounter].width / 2;
        bmVisArr[loaderCounter].y =-bmVisArr[loaderCounter].height / 2;

        ShapeArr[loaderCounter] = new Sprite();
        ShapeArr[loaderCounter].name = a.substr(7,4);

        trace("Name",loaderCounter,ShapeArr[loaderCounter].name );

        ShapeArr[loaderCounter].addChild(bmVisArr[loaderCounter]);
        loader[loaderCounter].contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        if (loaderCounter <numPicsToLoad-1) {
            loaderCounter += 1;
            initiateLoaders();
        }
        //trace("gonna count",count);
        counting();
        count += 1;
    }

    private function counting():void {
        trace("tile count", count,numPicsToLoad);
        if (count < numPicsToLoad-1) {
            return;
        }
        else{
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, counting);
            loaded = true;
            count = 0;
            trace("All Images LOADED");
        }
    }   
}//end  Class
}//end Package
```