# AS3 Event.COMPLETE passing argument

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to pass an argument on Event.Complete, so once they load the image, i can handle them accordingly of the position, store them, etc. See below the code and the output:

```
var pic:Array = ["https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png","https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png","https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png","https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"];

for (var ii: uint = 0; ii < pic.length; ii++) {

var imageURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pic[ii]); 
var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
myImageLoader.load(imageURLRequest); 
trace ("the ii: " + ii);

myImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event)
{
   doIt(evt, ii)
} , false, 0, true);

function doIt(evt:Event, msg:int) {
    //var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myImageLoader.width, myImageLoader.height); 
    //myBitmapData.draw(myImageLoader); 
    //var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap; 
    //myBitmap.bitmapData = myBitmapData; 
    trace ("message : " + msg);
}
}

/////Output
the ii: 0
the ii: 1
the ii: 2
the ii: 3

message : 4
message : 4
message : 4
message : 4

///Expected Output

/////Output
the ii: 0
the ii: 1
the ii: 2
the ii: 3

message : 0 
message : 1
message : 2
message : 3
```

Thank for the help
Speego

Comment: The thing is, the loop finishes before any actual loading happens, so **ii** is 4 at the moment any of these **COMPLETE** events occur. Hence, the output. In order to differ these loading processes you need to wrap them with a class (or extend the **Loader** class) so you can have custom fields set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have been researching about extender or wrapper but i cannot make it work :( .... this one it is the closest one i got, but i keep getting error mismatch on arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532177/as3-how-do-i-get-dynamic-loader-url-from-loaderinfo-in-event-listener-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know, the **Loader** class inherits from **DisplayObject** which in turn means you have access to the **.name** property.

Having this in mind you can 'abuse' this property to store the value of your **ii** variable as a string and send it to the doIt() function as the second parameter - after casting it back to an integer.

So simply change this:

```
var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
```

to this:

```
var myImageLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
myImageLoader.name = ii.toString();
```

and the onComplete callback handler to this:

```
myImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event):void
{
doIt(evt, int(flash.display.LoaderInfo(evt.target).loader.name));
}, false, 0, true);
```

This should give you an output like this:

```
the ii: 0
the ii: 1
the ii: 2
the ii: 3
message : 1
message : 0
message : 3
message : 2
```